# Trouble in Running my first android app in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am totally new to android and just started reading The Big Nerd Ranch Book: Android Programming.

Everything was progressing good until I tried to start the emulator and run the first chapter project.

When I run the project in emulator, first I get something like the image below:

https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/ZcvF

and by moving and sweeping the mouse I get this one:

https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/Zcvf

Where can I see the result of the program (The two buttons and the action on it). Have I done everything right?

Edited:

Here is my XML Layout:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp" 
        android:text="@string/question_text"/>

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
          android:id="@+id/true_button"      
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/true_button" />

        <Button
          android:id="@+id/false_button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/false_button" />

      </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

And here is my activity class:

package com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Quizctivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quizctivity);

        mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(Quizctivity.this,R.string.incorrect_toast , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(Quizctivity.this, R.string.correct_toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quizctivity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and here you can find a snapshot of the emulator settings:

-- imageupload.co.uk/image/ZcMn

and finally here is the layout that I want to see when I run the project:

-- imageupload.co.uk/image/ZcQT

Thanks in advance

Comment: read the console, and read the logcat, click on the application you created in the emulator

Comment: Could u post some code please!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses. I edited my post to include XML Layout and Activity Class.